# Carbon diffInDays não trás o valor negativo entre duas datas (somente positivos)

Tags: php, laravel

```
$datNow = Carbon::parse('2018-10-23 18:40:11.000000');
$datSuspensao = Carbon::parse('2018-10-18 00:00:00.390176');
$diasRestantes  = $datSuspensao->diffInDays($datNow);

dd($diasRestantes);
//Imprime 5 (Na verdade queria imprimir -5)

$datNow = Carbon::parse('2018-10-23 18:40:11.000000');
$datSuspensao = Carbon::parse('2018-10-18 00:00:00.390176');
$diasRestantes  = $datSuspensao->diffInDays($datNow, false); //Coloquei false como segundo parâmetro e não deu certo

dd($diasRestantes);
//Continua imprimindo 5

$datNow = Carbon::parse('2018-10-23 18:40:11.000000');
$datSuspensao = Carbon::parse('2018-10-18 00:00:00.390176');
$diasRestantes  = $datSuspensao->diffForHumans($datNow);

dd($diasRestantes);
//Imprime "5 dias atrás"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A data tem que ser a maior, para que o dado tire a diferença negativa, exemplo:

***Código:***

```
$datNow = Carbon::parse('2018-10-23 18:40:11.000000');
$datSuspensao = Carbon::parse('2018-10-18 00:00:00.390176');

//A data maior faz a diferença na data menor
$diasRestantes = $datNow->diffInDays($datSuspensao, false);
```

***Resultado:***

```
-5
```

***Referencia:***

- [Laravel and Carbon - DiffInDays If Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47946778/laravel-and-carbon-diffindays-if-statement)
- [Carbon - Introduction](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)